# Starting the plot at a specific number of ticks

Tags: plot, time, netlogo

For my model, I want to count the number of evacuated turtles from the moment the evacuation starts.

I have a counter that starts counting seconds and minutes, untill every turtle is out of the model (has been evacuated).

This is the procedure for the counter:

```
to setuptime
  let minutes_string (word minutes)
  let seconds_string (word seconds)
  if seconds < 10 [ set seconds_string (word "0" seconds)]
  if minutes < 10 [ set minutes_string (word "0" minutes)]
  set current_time (word minutes_string ":" seconds_string)
end
```

Now I want to plot the number of evacuated turtles, starting once the evacuation starts. The evacuation starts when I push the button 'Start a fire'.

So on the y-axis, I have the number of evacuated turtles. And on the x-axis, I want the amount of evacuation time once the fire starts.

But how do I make the plot start when the evacuation starts? Now it just starts when the ticks start.

The code for the fire button:

```
to startfire
  set initial-attendees count turtles
  if alarm [
    ask patches with [pycor > -2 and pycor < 4 and (pxcor > 1 and pxcor < 4)] [set pcolor red]
    ask patches with [pycor > -160 and pycor < -154 and (pxcor < 120 and pxcor > 117)] [set pcolor red]
    ask patches with [pycor > -2 and pycor < 4 and (pxcor > -3 and pxcor < 0)] [set pcolor red]
    ask patches with [pycor > -160 and pycor < -154 and (pxcor > -120 and pxcor < -117)] [set pcolor red]]
  set alarm? true
end
```

The code for the plot is what I am looking for. I calculate the number of evacuated turtles by counting the initial-attendees - count attendees.

Comment: Do minutes and seconds relate to ticks in some way? That procedure prints out some variables in a time format, but it it not a counter of any sort. Regardless, your question is about starting your plots - could you please provide the code for your plot, and also the code for the button that you use to start a fire.

Comment: I have added the codes into the question!

Answer (score 2):

I still am not clear how time relates to ticks etc. The code below is a simple complete model that starts plotting after a few ticks. The way it does it is that `plot-pen-up` is in the setup code, so the plotting pen doesn't do anything. Once a few ticks in, the `plot-pen-down` starts the plotting.

```
to setup
  clear-all
  create-turtles 20 [setxy random-xcor random-ycor]
  plot-pen-up
  reset-ticks
end

to go
  ask n-of random 5 turtles [hatch 1 right 90]
  ask n-of random 5 turtles [die]
  ask turtles [forward 1]
  if ticks = 5 [plot-pen-down]
  tick
end
```

The plot simply has the plot command of `plot count turtles`.

In your case, if you have multiple plots, you will need something a bit more sophisticated to say which pens are up or down. You would have the `plot-pen-down` command as part of your starting the fire code.